# azure ml workspace data asset

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-bicep

Issue with Creating Data Asset Version using Bicep

On the initial attempt, the creation process works seamlessly. However, subsequent attempts result in the following error:
YAML

```
A data version with this name and version already exists. If you are aiming to establish a new data version, please utilize a distinct name or version. For updates to an existing data version, it is worth noting that the asset's data URI cannot be altered. Only attributes such as tags, description, and isArchived can be updated. (Code: UserError)
```

It's important to emphasize that I haven't made any modifications to the version in question. Here's the current code snippet for reference:

```
resource dataAssetVersion 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/data/versions@2023-04-01' = {
  parent: data
  name: dataAssetversion
  properties: {
    dataType: 'uri_folder'
    isAnonymous: false
    dataUri: 'azureml://datastores/${datastore.name}/paths/csv'
    description: 'random description'
    isArchived: false
  }
}
```

Comment: from the error message it looks like you specified a new `dataUri`? Can you check that this property is still the same please

Comment: I hardcoded the name and redeployed. First deploy went trrough, second failed
  dataUri: 'azureml://datastores/testname/paths/csv'

Comment: Oh ok, let me have a look as well then. Also can you confirm the `dataType` is the same on the parent resource ?

Comment: Confirm its the same

resource data 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/data@2023-04-01' = {
  name: datasetName
  parent: workspace
  properties: {
    dataType: 'uri_folder'
    description: 'Dataset description'
    isArchived: false
  }
}

Comment: Ok so I can reproduce putting some fake values, would you be able to share your data store bicep as well (updating the question) wondering if there is an issue connecting to the data store using the provided uri.

Comment: If you could let me know what type of data store you are targetting that would be great

Comment: I dont think its a problem connecxting to datastore, since first deploy work, and I can view the data when i brows. However the data store is a blob storage: container with folder /csv

Comment: are you using the default data store `workspaceblobstore`? with the auto generated container name `azureml-blobstore-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`?

Comment: Was looking at that it seems bicep doesnt like the store path the second time

Comment: yeah, which is very weird since the path hasnt changed. It should not update 
No not default, i've created a data store and data asset and are trying to create version for the data asset

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments section, I've created a new blob store and it gave me the same error:

```
param workspaceName string
param dataStoreName string
param dataAssetName string
param dataAssetVersionName string
param dataType string = 'uri_folder'
param dataDescription string = 'Sample data asset'
param isArchived bool = false

resource mlWorkspace 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces@2023-06-01-preview' existing = {
  name: workspaceName
}

resource blobStore 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/datastores@2023-06-01-preview' existing = {
  name: dataStoreName
  parent: mlWorkspace
}

resource dataAsset 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/data@2023-06-01-preview' existing = {
  name: dataAssetName
  parent: mlWorkspace
}

resource dataAssetVersion 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/data/versions@2023-06-01-preview' = {
  name: dataAssetVersionName
  parent: dataAsset
  properties: {
    dataType: dataType
    dataUri: 'azureml://datastores/${blobStore.name}/paths/csv'
    isArchived: isArchived
    description: dataDescription
  }
}
```

I checked the data asset created using the ARM API and I could see the dataUri was different:

```
az rest --method get `
  --uri /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/<ml-workspace-name>/data/<data-assest-name>/versions/<version-name>?api-version=2023-06-01-preview
```

Command result:

```json
{
  ...
  "properties": {
    ...
    "dataUri": "azureml://subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourcegroups/<rg-name>/workspaces/<ml-workspace-name>/datastores/<data-store-name>/paths/csv/",
    ... 
  },
  ...  
}
```

I've updated my bicep template like that and it worked as expected

```
resource dataAssetVersion 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/data/versions@2023-06-01-preview' = {
  name: dataAssetVersionName
  parent: dataAsset
  properties: {
    dataType: dataType
    dataUri: 'azureml://subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/${resourceGroup().name}/workspaces/${mlWorkspace.name}/datastores/${blobStore.name}/paths/csv/'
    isArchived: isArchived
    description: dataDescription
  }
}
```

I imagine the `azureml://datastores/${blobStore.name}/paths/csv` uri is just a shortcut uri used my the ML service but that the underlying ARM API is translated to something longer `azureml://subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/${resourceGroup().name}/workspaces/${mlWorkspace.name}/datastores/${blobStore.name}/paths/csv/`